# Se mirent en perspective

Tags: vocabulaire

l'expression écrite en caractère gras veut dire quoi exactement:

> il considéra les actions sans vertige, il examina les personnages sans terreur ; la révolution et l’empire **se mirent** lumineusement **en perspective** devant sa prunelle visionnaire.

Source: [Les Miserables Tome III](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/06)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/perspective)

> B. − Au fig.
>
> 1. Manière particulière d'envisager les choses ou d'en interpréter le déroulement; aspect sous lequel les choses se présentent. Synon. angle, optique, point de vue*.Aucune existence dans la perspective biblique n'est monadique (Philos., Relig., 1957, p.40-1):
> 2. C'est ce journal-là, ou un autre, peu importe, que je lirai là-bas. En tout cas, une édition de Paris. Ce sont des nouvelles arrangées de cette façon-là, dosées comme ça, qui m'arriveront. La perspective du monde qui sera, chaque matin, que je le veuille ou non, la mienne. Romains,Hommes bonne vol., 1932, p.157.
>
> − Loc. adv. En perspective. Avec du recul. Il nous faut voir la vie en perspective. Mais il n'est point de perspective ni d'espace, le jour où l'on enterre (Saint-Exup.,Pilote guerre, 1942, p.276).

Answer (score 2):

Dans le cas présent, l'expression *se mettre en perspective* est proche de *voir sous un nouveau jour*. Il y a une connotation de compréhension. Lorsqu'on voit un cube en perspective, on est conscient qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un carré.

On notera que *en perspective* est aussi utilisé dans des locutions telles que *sous/selon la perspective de [quelqu'un/quelque chose]*, dans ces cas-là on indique que l'angle sous lequel on regarde a une importance, car il y a plusieurs façons de voir la même chose.